# How to create a slanted rectangle like the image below

Tags: html, css

I am building my website after creating a wireframe with figma but now I have a problem with coding this slanted rectangle which i use for most of my headers/page titles. I have seen several examples online which use only one-sided slanting but my case is slanted on both sides.

**Image**

[image: the image]

Comment: What have you tried? Where is your code? Please read: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 0):

Everything is correct except the slanted rectangle part. I have added skew transform property which will generate the output as intended.

```css
 .block {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    transform: translateY(3.3rem);
}
.line {
    transform: translateY(5rem);
    border: 1px solid black;
}
.subscribe {
    width: 200px;
    height: 50px;
    background-color: black;
    color: white;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    font-size: 1.5rem;
    font-style: italic;
    transform: skew(-20deg);
    text-transform: uppercase;
}
```

```html
<div class="line"></div>
<div class="block">
    <div class="subscribe">Subscribe</div>
</div>
```